# javascript - How to trigger a function call only once on click - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I have attached an onclick eventhandler to a button. On click, I want to show data (a todo list). The problem is that every time I click on that button I keep calling the function-adding the same elements to the DOM. I couldn't really find a solution online and nothing I tried worked. Any ideas? Thanks!

ps. I am trying to use only javascript and no Jquery.

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
    var button=document.querySelector("#showTodos");
    button.onclick = showAll;
}

function showAll () {
    var ul = document.getElementById("todoList");
    var listFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();    
    var todos = LocalStorageHelper.read("todos") || [];
    todos.map(function(item){
            var li = create(item);
            listFragment.appendChild(li);            
    })

    ul.appendChild(listFragment);
}

//What I tried (and which doesnt work):
 button.onclick = !showAll ? showAll : null;

// Also tried: defining a variable, setting boolean to false and insight the function to true. That doesnt work too, and even if it did, I would need to define a variable as a global variable which I wouldnt want.

var called=false;
button.onclick = !called ? showAll : null;
```

Comment: Why not just disable it, or remove it?

Comment: Attach event listener function to a button; inside this listener remove event listener from button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the handler when invoked

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
    var button=document.querySelector("#showTodos");
    button.onclick = showAll;
}

function showAll () {
    var ul = document.getElementById("todoList");
    var listFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();    
    var todos = LocalStorageHelper.read("todos") || [];
    todos.map(function(item){
            var li = create(item);
            listFragment.appendChild(li);            
    })

    ul.appendChild(listFragment);
    button.onclick = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just detach the handler after it executed once:

```
  function showAll () {
   this.removeEventListener("click", showAll);
   //...
  }

  button.addEventListener("click", showAll);
```

If you somewhen move to jquery, its even simpler. Just do

```
 $(button).once("click", function showAll(){ /*...*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove the handler or store a `data-attribute` to mark it as executed:

```
button.addEventListener('click', showAll);

function showAll() {
    if (this.dataset.executed) return;
    this.dataset.executed = "true";
    .
    .
    // Execute logic
});
```